# uib-tooltip-html it gives me a syntax error

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code.

```
<button uib-tooltip-html='Review Requested <br>test' 
class="btn btn-default"><span class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></span>
    </button>
```

and I am getting the following error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Requested' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [Review Requested <br> test] starting at [Requested <br> test].
```

Answer (score 0):

This closed [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4738) on GitHub makes it sound like the value needs to be wrapped in an element. For example:

```
<button uib-tooltip-html='<div>Review Requested <br>test</div>' 
class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
  var app = angular.module("test").config(function($sceProvider) {
            $sceProvider.enabled(false);
        });

 app.controller("testController", function($scope, $sce) {
     $scope.getToolTipHTML= function() {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml('<div>Review Requested <br>test</div>');
        }
    });
```

```html
<button uib-tooltip-html='getToolTipHTML()' class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></span>
</button>
```